# Software recommendation for a video player that supports Chromecast casting

Tags: software-recommendation, video-player, chromecast

VLC is not launching on my HP ProBook 440 G8 Notebook PC.I want to watch video on TV I request a list of video player applications that support Chromecast casting.

Comment: "Give me". You are talking to humans here. Have a look around first on other questions and answers to get an idea what kind of voice, what kind of respect people use with each other, and expect from each other, here.

Comment: From our [code of conduct](https://askubuntu.com/conduct): "a safe and welcoming community rooted in kindness, cooperation and mutual respect"; "we expect all users to treat one another with kindness and respect".

Comment: I figure, it may be possible that English is not your first language and you don't have adequate control over the tone of voice you end up using. If this is the case, here are some ideas that can offer a first-aid to the situation: Adding the word "please" could always take away the unpleasant edge of those sentences. Also, replacing the imperative "give me" with such neutral statements as "I need", or "I request" could also avoid a needlessly edgy tone.

Comment: I replaced the "give me" with "I request" and tagged the question more logically.

Comment: I do not think the original wording was rude, but merely childish. "Give me list" without the grammatically required article "a" sounds like children saying "gimme" in primary school. I didn't interpret the imperative mood here as a demand, but rather as nagging

Answer (score 1):

VLC is packaged in both apt and snap package formats in Ubuntu. If one of the two package formats of VLC doesn't work try installing the other VLC package.

#### MPV

- Simple, customizable and lightweight video player
- Built-in in Ubuntu and installable with `sudo apt install mpv`
- Supports a wide range of video and audio formats
- Native Chromecast casting (no extensions needed)

#### GNOME Videos

- Default video player for the GNOME desktop environment
- Built-in in Ubuntu and installable with `sudo apt install totem`
- Won't play some common video formats
- Chromecast casting is available through the "Cast to TV" GNOME Shell extension in the Extension Manager app (`sudo apt install extension-manager`).

#### Kodi

- Media center application with a large library of add-ons
- Installable with `sudo apt install kodi`
- More complex to set up and use than VLC or MPV
- Supports Chromecast casting through the unofficial "YouTube" add-on. The YouTube add-on is a mess to install.

Comment: @AvhraNeilSen Please accept my answer by clicking the gray checkmark beside it which makes it change color from gray to green. Clicking the up pointing triangle upvotes the answer.